# What do these lines mean?

Tags: c#

Sorry for the very vague question, but I'm not really sure how to Google/ask this.

Basically, I've seen these 2 (similar) lines in a lot of c# code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
```

and

```
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
```

In the first snippet, what is it actually doing. What are the `[ ]` used for?

In the second snippet, what is the `<string>` declaration called so I can find more information on it.

Thanks!

Comment: It's referrencing(sp) Windows API from C#. I do not know what the second part means.

Comment: The first place you went to (the documentation), what part confused you?

Comment: `[]` = Attributes. `<T>` = Generics.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead answered the question.

Comment: why all the downvotes?  this is a straightforward question, with a straightforward answers.  why would you want to make the OP feel bad for trying to learn about the language?  i don't get the aggressive downvoting on this site.

Comment: @Jason I think people generally downvote for things that are covered thousands of times across this site and every single C#/.NET book. At least, that's what I've observed..

Comment: It would help a lot to know the code of context. If your code contains things you do not understand, and you are asking only in fragments of code, it's a standard red flag.

Comment: Asking 2+ absolutely unrelated questions at once is questionable practice...

Comment: @BrendanScarvell I don't mean to be "that guy", but searching Google for "C# angle brackets" produces the MSDN topic on Generics as the first hit.. :/

Comment: Or even start simpler. Start by looking up DllImport and Task<string> + C#. That would get you to attributes and generics from a meaningful, built-in example.

Comment: `Task<TResult>` link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[DllImport("user32.dll")]`

- The `DllImport` attribute allows you to specify the name of the DLL that contains the method. The common practice is to name the C# method the same as the exported method, but you can also use a different name for the C# method.

See [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

`Task<string>` -- see [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> Like   [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]  ?

There are two ways that C# code can directly call unmanaged code:

1.**Directly call a function exported from a DLL.**

2.Call an interface method on a COM object (for more information on this ,that you havent asked!, see COM Interop Part
 C# Client Tutorial).

> **Simply**,  `DllImport` and `dllexport` enable interop with DLL files. We
>   can use a C++ DLL dynamic link library, or a custom legacy DLL—even
>   one we can't rewrite but have the ability to modify.

best tutor :http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport

> **Calling a DLL Export Directly from C#**
>   To declare a method as having an implementation from a DLL export, do the following:
>   Declare the method with the static and extern C# keywords.
>   Attach the DllImport attribute to the method. The DllImport attribute allows you to specify the name of the DLL that contains the
>   method. The common practice is to name the C# method the same as the
>   exported method, but you can also use a different name for the C# method.
>   Optionally, specify custom marshaling information for the method's parameters and return value, which will override the .NET
>   Framework default marshaling.

**Example 1**

```
This example shows you how to use the DllImport attribute to output a message by calling puts from msvcrt.dll.

// PInvokeTest.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest
{
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    public static extern int puts(string c);
    [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
    internal static extern int _flushall();

    public static void Main() 
    {
        puts("Test");
        _flushall();
    }
}
```

> Output
>
> Test

---

**Strict References**

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C 
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/211613-very-basic-introduction-to-tasks/ 
http://www.basarat.com/2011/06/best-tutorial-of-c-async.html